# What is the best C# to VB.net converter?

Tags: c#, vb.net, converters

While searching the interweb for a solution for my VB.net problems I often find helpful articles on a specific topic, but the code is C#. That is no big problem but it cost some time to convert it to VB manually.
There are some sites that offer code converters from C# to VB and vice versa, but to fix all the flaws after the code-conversion is nearly as time-consuming as doing it by myself in the first place.

Till now I am using http://labs.developerfusion.co.uk/convert/csharp-to-vb.aspx

Do you know something better?

Comment: Closed so we'll never know if there is a better one than there was in 2008

Comment: ILSpy is working for me in 2016. Pretty much the same thing as the accepted Reflector answer.

Comment: Anyone who lands here, I have been using [Econ Netvert](https://econnetvert.codeplex.com/) for ages and it works smoothly most of the time and is **offline**. Just make sure you select **ICSharp 4.0** from the providers list (top-right). Note that it doesn't handle some of the new language constructs (lambdas, anonymous functions, null-coalescing), but otherwise works fine 95% of the time. Works both ways (C# <-> VB.NET) and can handle entire projects too. Note that the project is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you cannot find a good converter, you could always compile the c# code and use the dissasembler in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to see Visual Basic code. Some of the variable names will change.

Comment: Unfortunaly, the decompiler to VB in Reflector is quite buggy.
Often you'll end up with code that compiles, but produces different results.
Try this as a test case to evaluate code converters:
double x = 3 / 2;
double y = 3.0 / 2;
int z = (int)(-3.5);

"x" should be 1.0 (many converters produce code that results in x=1.5), y should be 1.5, z should be -3 (many converters produce code that results in z=-4)

Comment: Note: to see the problems I mentioned in Reflector, you need to use temporary variables, otherwise the C# compiler optimizes the calculation away and the bug in Reflector isn't triggered.

Answer (score 23):

Telerik has [a good converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) that is based on SharpDevelop that has worked pretty well over the years, though it has not been updated in years (due to it being based on SharpDevelop).

I've recently come across a [roslyn based converter as well](http://web.archive.org/web/20180312203225/http://roslyncodeconverter.azurewebsites.net:80/). I don't know how well it works or how well maintained it is, but as it's open source you can always fork it and update it as needed.

Comment: This has a handy option to upload a zip of source and then download a zip with them all converted and a conversion error report.

Comment: It no longer converts comments! No feedback support

Comment: please see my edits @eschneider. maybe the new one will work better for you.

Comment: Just tried it again, not working at all now. System.NotSupportedException: NotInheritableKeyword not supported!

Comment: Few other issues I see: vb.net collections .Item(0) fails, .ToString fails "Note missing ()". nameof fails "Case issues, others like this", vb.net arrays vs c# array issues "() vs []" and line spacing is not maintained

Comment: roslyn version works but still no comments

Comment: The SharpDevelop converter you mentioned also has a [Visual Studio extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SharpDevelopTeam.CodeConverter) which is much more accurate since it uses the project context.

Answer (score 13):

I currently use these two most often:

http://converter.telerik.com/

http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

But have also had some success with these others:

http://converter.atomproject.net/

http://www.dotnetspider.com/convert/Csharp-To-Vb.aspx

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 12):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) has a built-in translator between C# and VB.NET. Is not perfect thought (e.g. the optional values in VB.NET doesn't have an equivalent in C#, so the signature of the converter method must be edited), but you can save some time, as you are making all operations inside an IDE and not a webpage (copy C# code, paste, hit button, copy VB.NET code, paste on IDE :P )

Answer (score 11):

I think the best thing to do is learn enough of the other language so that you can rewrite by hand, there's some quite difficult differences in certain aspects that I'm not sure a converter would handle very well. For example, compare my translation from C# to VB of the following:

```
public class FileSystemEventSubscription : EventSubscription
{
    private FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher;

    public FileSystemEventSubscription(IComparable queueName, 
        Guid workflowInstanceId, FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher) : base(queueName, workflowInstanceId)
    {
        this.fileSystemWatcher = fileSystemWatcher;
    }
```

becomes

```
Public Class FileSystemEventSubscription
    Inherits EventSubscription  
    Private myFileSystemWatcher As FileSystemWatcher
    Public Sub New(ByVal QueueName As IComparable, ByVal WorkflowInstanceID As Guid, ByVal Watcher As FileSystemWatcher)
        MyBase.New(QueueName, WorkflowInstanceID)
        Me.myFileSystemWatcher = Watcher
    End Sub
```

The C# is from the Custom Activity Framework sample, and I'm afraid I've lost the link to it. But it contains some nasty looking inheritance (from a VB point of view).

Comment: If you put your example into https://roslyncodeconverter.azurewebsites.net/ it converts the same as your hand written version (except that you changed the names of things in your handmade conversion)

Answer (score 5):

I am using a free Visual Studio 2012 plug-in named [Language Convert](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/cc8da841-f978-4c3e-8397-c820bd57298c)

It works perfectly on 2010/2012, unfortunately isn't working at VS 2013 yet.

The conversion is not 100% accurate, but it is definitely very helpful, to launch for the first time it is a bit tricky, check before the image below : [image]

Answer (score 4):

Last I checked, [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/) has one and it is open source too.

Answer (score 3):

You can load your DLL or EXE into Redgate's (formerly Lutz Roeder's) [.Net Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), select your method and then the desired language from the language combo. The code of the selected method will be displayed in the selected language.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one [converter](http://converter.atomproject.net/). There is functionality for C# to VB and VB to C#.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Carlos Aguilar Mares has had an online converter for about 40 forevers - [Code Translator](http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/Default.aspx) **but I would agree that Reflector is the better answer.**

Answer (score 2):

While not answering your question, I will say that I have been in a similar position.

I realised that code samples in C# were awkward when I was really starting out in .NET, but a few weeks into my first project (after I grown more familiar with the .NET framework and VB.NET itself), I found that it was interesting and sometimes beneficial to have to reverse-engineer the C# code. Not just in terms of syntax, but also learning about the subtle differences in approach - it's useful to be open-minded in this respect.

I'm sticking with VB.NET as I learn more and more about the framework, but before long I'll dip my to into C# with the intention of becoming 'multi-lingual'.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I use a plugin for VS2005 that I found on CodeProject (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Code_convert_add-in.aspx); it use an external service (http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/) to perform translation.

Occasionally, when I'm offline, I use a converter tool (http://www.kamalpatel.net/ConvertCSharp2VB.aspx).

Comment: Links 1st & 3rd are broken now.

Answer (score 1):

The one at http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ (new url) now supports .NET 3.5 syntax (thanks to the #develop guys once again), and will automatically copy the results to your clipboard :)