# C# VB.NET Conversion

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Which tools do you use to convert between C# and VB.NET?

Comment: this is the third question like this. use the search!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best C# to VB.net converter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88359/what-is-the-best-c-sharp-to-vb-net-converter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been asked so many times. Like here: [What is the best C# to VB.net converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88359/what-is-the-best-c-to-vbnet-converter)

Comment: I searched "c# vb.net converter" and "c# vb.net conversion", and nothing came up. Any thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps C# is killing the search. I found it with vb.net conversion.

Answer (score 8):

Check out [Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) by Telerik.

Answer (score 4):

[Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector). It isn't the best for the task, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Tangible has C++ <> C#, Java <> C#, VB <> C# etc. I'm not sure how to quantify which is "best" but their support is responsive if there's a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use snippet converter for converting code..[snippet converter](http://codeconverter.sharpdevelop.net/SnippetConverter.aspx)