# Converting C# console app to VB.NET and VBA

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vba

I have to convert a C# project to VB.NET and VBA. It's a console app that uses the Microsoft Office API (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.*`).

My two questions:

- C# -> VB.NET: .NET Reflector is a good tool for this, except that it doesn't preserve source code comments. Is there a way to do this?
- .NET -> VBA: is there an automated tool to do this conversion? It would need to be a client side tool (because the code is proprietary).

Comment: Why does the C# have to be converted to VB.NET? Seems pointless to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best conversion seems to be done by SharpDevelop.  Open your project and from the tools menu and select convert code to.  Since it has all of your c# source code it does a very good job.

Comment: +1 I have had good luck with using SharpDevelops built in conversion tool.

Answer (score 1):

There are [many ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88359/what-is-the-best-c-to-vbnet-converter) to convert C# to VB.Net; for example, try [Developer Fusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).

It is not possible to automatically convert C# to VBA because the environment, language, and libraries are radically different.  However, you could expose the C# code as a COM server and call it from a thin wrapper in VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for question #1:

You cannot use Reflector to preserve source code comments because Reflector is disassembling the compiled code, which has had all comments removed.

Consider using a commercial tool like InstantVB, which will converts C# source code into VB source code (including comments):
http://tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_VB.html

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the C# source code to VB.Net manually with this:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

which *will* preserve comments.  As far as automatically converting C# to VBA or VB6, I'd be willing to say that that is almost certainly going to be completely impossible.  There are many aspects of C#/.Net that are not available in VBA or VB6 (like inheritance, for one).