# How to hook up ClickI() event for ImageButton in code behind ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a ImageButton instance variable in my custom control I am making. I am a little shaky on how to simply **set up it's event handler for it's click event**. Coming from C#, I am a little confused as this is in VB.NET.

Snip:

```
Dim ctrlCloseImage As ImageButton = New ImageButton()
    With ctrlCloseImage
        .ID = "imgClose"
        .ImageUrl = "~/Web/Images/close.gif"
        .ToolTip = "Close"
        .CssClass = "popup_close_img"
        'This is where I left off
        AddHandler ctrlCloseImage.Click, AddressOf testSub(ctrlCloseImage, ??)
    End With
Me._ctrlCloseImage = ctrlCloseImage
```

And Then:

```
Protected Sub testSub(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs)
    Me.Page.Response.Write("Yay, you clicked the image button!")
End Sub
```

Thanks for any help, and if I am missing anything important code-snip wise please let me know. Again, I am wanting this to fire server side, I am not interested in firing off a javascript function here.

Comment: You may want to convert your vb.net code to c# code. I would.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88359/what-is-the-best-c-sharp-to-vb-net-converter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to add the delegate:

```
AddHandler ctrlCloseImage.Click, AddressOf testSub
```

You cannot pass arguments since the event is not triggered here.

However, if you don't need to create a control dynamically (normally that's unnecessary) you could either register the event on the aspx or with the `Handles` clause(as opposed to C#):

```
Protected Sub testSub(ByVal Sender As Object, ByVal e As ImageClickEventArgs) _
    Handles ctrlCloseImage.Click
    Me.Page.Response.Write("Yay, you clicked the image button!")
End Sub
```

Comment: Ahhh.....so close....yet so far. Will accept this when it allows me to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the click event a handler :

```
AddHandler ctrlCloseImage.Click, AddressOf testSub
```

This will assign the `Click` control the handler of address `testSub`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (just put the name of the method afyer AddressOf):

```
AddHandler ctrlCloseImage.Click, AddressOf testSub
```