# ASP.NET ImageButton Click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I have a dynamic ImageButton and I want it to trigger a method when it's clicked. I have the following code, which unfortunatelly it's not working.

```
ImageButton imb = new ImageButton();
imb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
        imb.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(ImageButton1_Click);
        imb.ID = "ID";
        imb.ImageUrl = "link to image";
Panel1.Controls.Add(imb);

protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    //it should go here
}
```

Comment: You spelled `runat` wrong. Also, OnClientClick is for javascript, remove that. Is there some reason you can't just put the control on the page?

Comment: [Version in VB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098325/how-to-hook-up-clicki-event-for-imagebutton-in-code-behind-asp-net).

Comment: Fixed 'runat' and removed OnClientClick. The control is added to an ASP Panel, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Update your question with the current code.

Comment: Question updated with the current code.

Comment: imb.Attributes.Add("runat", "server"); not needed at all because it is only needed in aspx /ascx markup only. while adfing from code behind it's not needed. also dynamically added control need to be added always on PostBack.

Answer (score 0):

you must add your ImageButton to a suitable continer.

e.g:

```
 form1.Controls.Add(Imb);
 /// form1 must have runat=server
```

you can find useful tips at [here](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337268/asp-runat-server-for-dynamic-control).

Comment: Yes, it is in a ASP Panel.

Panel1.Controls.Add(imb);

Answer (score 0):

Adding dynamic controls to the page is a tricky matter. Unfortunately, you cannot just declare an object of `WebControl` derived type and expect it to work.

In ASP.NET WebForms, there is a concept called [Page Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). It is a broad matter, but my point is that there is a particular order you must obey to plug-in the dynamic control into the page. A practical example follows.

Start with dynamic control declaration at the class level.

```
protected ImageButton imb = null;
```

Then you initialize it durring the page initialization. One possibility is to handle the [PreInit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.preinit.aspx) event.

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imb = new ImageButton()
    {
        ID = "ID",
        ImageUrl = "link to image"
    };

    imb.Click += Imb_Click;

    Panel1.Controls.Add(imb);

}

private void Imb_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your stuff
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // Set initial properties as appropriate. E.g.
        imb.AlternateText = "...";
    }
}
```

You're good to go.